# How can I make a redirect page in jQuery/JavaScript when using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

How can I redirect the user from one page to another using jQuery -> Ajax?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: What have you tried? And why do you want to do this? Why not just use a link to send the user to another page? Or are you already using AJAX to do something and want to send the user after the callback?

Comment: Using ajax to redirect is the exact opposite of it's intended use.

Comment: On success call of ajax set "window.location.reload=data.url" where url is the string you have returned from the called method

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-using-jquery

Answer (score 3):

Try this if you want to redirect to another page once ajax call is success,

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "page1.html",
    success:function(result){
        document.location.href="page2.html";
    }});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://where.to/redirect",,
        async:false,
    });
```

This will load the url synchroniously, that means redirect the user "in jquery/javascript when using ajax".
To "make a redirect page", write this:

```
    <script type="application/javascript" language="javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://where.to/redirect",,
        async:false,
    });
    </script>
```

... tada! We have a "a redirect page in jQuery/JavaScript when using ajax"! ;)

Answer (score 0):

// Through an HTTP redirect

window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// Through by clicking on a link

window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";